# Range of probability for watching all 4 movies

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

I'm doing some work in R and have the following problem.

A streaming service company collected data on TV shows viewings of a pool of 9690 subscribers, with the intent of deploying a more efficient content recommendation system. For each subscriber, the data record the TV series watched in a period of 12 months. The following tables report summaries of the frequencies of occurrence of 4 shows in particular: Chernobyl, Daredevil, Ozark, Stranger Things.

```
Movie              Count
-------------------------
Ozark              1877
Stranger Things    1070
Daredevil          910
Chernobyl          506
```

EDIT** adding in extra tables info:

```
Pairs                           Count
----------------------------------------
Daredevil - Ozark               261
Stranger Things - Ozark         242
Chernobyl - Ozark               140
Daredevil - Stranger Things     117
Chernobyl - Stranger Things     82
Cherbonyl - Daredevil           65

Triplets                                    Count
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Daredevil - Stranger Things - Ozark                 50
Chernobyl - Stranger Things - Ozark                 27
Chernobyl - Daredevil - Ozark                       21
Chernobyl - Daredevil - Stranger Things             6
```

Given the information in the tables above, provide an appropriate range for the estimate of the probability that a customer watched all the 4 TV shows.
My understanding is the events are not mutually exclusive and should be calculated like the following https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-formula-for-calculating-the-total-probability-of-4-events-which-are-NOT-mutually-exclusive-occurring

P(AUBUCUD) = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) + P(D) - P(A∩B) - P(A∩C) - P(A∩D) - P(B∩C) - P(B∩D) - P(C∩D) + P(A∩B∩C) + P(A∩B∩D) + P(A∩C∩D) + P(B∩C∩D) - P(A∩B∩C∩D)

and that the probability of the intersections would be e.g. P(AnB) = p(A) * P(B), p(AnBnC) = P(A)*P(B)*P(C), P(A∩B∩C∩D) = P(A)*P(B)*P(C)*P(D) etc.

Is this the correct way of answering this problem? The thing throwing me off is the phrasing of the question 'appropriate range for the estimate of the probability'. Is it possible frechet bounds are meant to be used instead and if so can frechet bounds be used for 4 separate events?

Comment: If you have the dataset for the watchlists of all subscribers, a point estimate and interval estimate can easily be constructed for the probability of the intersection of events.  Calculate a new variable, $x$, for each subscriber that equals 1 if one of the shows of interest was watched and 0 otherwise.  Then $x_i \sim Bernoulli(p)$, where $p$ denotes the true but unknown probability of interest.  Then construct a point estimate and confidence interval for $p$.

Comment: Is the table you have given the **only** information you have?

Comment: Also have information on the pairs and triplets, will update the question accordingly